# How to get actual value of global variables in llvm

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang

For example:

```
int x=0;
int y=0;
```

where x and y are global variables, and in main() function we do the following:

```
x++;
y++;
```

How to get the newest value of global variables x and y in llvm.

when I try to do `errs()<<g;` they give the initial value as `@BB0 = global i32`
but I need to get the actual value like `x=1`, by using llvm.

Comment: When, exactly, are you running LLVM? Why do you expect it to know about run-time values?

Comment: I implement code in MCJIT to get all instructions. I want to get the value of global variable by its name after running lli file.ll

Comment: Is this possible, to get back the value of each global variable?

Answer (score 3):

A global is basically a pointer. You can get the address in the host program via [`ExecutionEngine::getGlobalValueAddress`](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1ExecutionEngine.html#a966d4ff307d844ac32c737a521bbecd5) and then you can dereference that address in order to get the stored value.

Comment: That is what I really need. Thank you

Comment: Moreover, is there a method to get real value of local variable. Not getValue() I want real value (like 1, 2, 3.5, etc)

Comment: @R.Omar as that's a new (although related) question, please ask that question separately.

Comment: Thank you , I have posted a new question

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44874575/getting-actual-value-of-local-variables-in-llvm/44925754#44925754] 
would you please answer this question urgently

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're using LLVM's API:

If the global is constant you can access its initialization value directly, for example:

```
Constant* myGlobal = new GlobalVariable( myLlvmModule, myLlvmType, true, GlobalValue::InternalLinkage, initializationValue );
...
Constant* constValue = myGlobal->getInitializer();
```

And if that value is of e.g. integer type, you can retrieve it like so:

```
ConstantInt* constInt = cast<ConstantInt>( constValue );
int64_t constIntValue = constInt->getSExtValue();
```

If the global isn't constant, you must load the data it points to (all globals are actually pointers):

```
Value* loadedValue = new LoadInst( myGlobal );
```