# Getting actual value of local variables in llvm

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-clang, llvm-ir

If I have this example:

```
int a=0, b=0;
```

a and b are local variables and make any modifications in their values, such as:

```
a++;
b++;
```

I need to get the value in this line code during running MCJIT.

I mean by value not `Value` class, but the actual integer or any type value.

Comment: will you pls give an example for this "I need to get the value in this line code during running MCJIT" explain little bit more

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the value from a JITed LLVM function in order to retrieve it from the code invoking MCJIT.

Check out this [Kaleidoscope example](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/llvm/blob/master/examples/Kaleidoscope/MCJIT/initial/toy.cpp).

The relevant code is in HandleTopLevelExpression():

```
if (FunctionAST *F = ParseTopLevelExpr()) {
  if (Function *LF = F->Codegen()) {
    // JIT the function, returning a function pointer.
    void *FPtr = TheHelper->getPointerToFunction(LF);

    // Cast it to the right type (takes no arguments, returns a double) so we
    // can call it as a native function.
    double (*FP)() = (double (*)())(intptr_t)FPtr;
    fprintf(stderr, "Evaluated to %f\n", FP());
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Put a break point after execution of the statement where you want to check the value. In the console `(lldb) po <variable name>`.

Although I guess watch point is more suitable for your requirement, add a watch point for the variable like, `watchpoint set variable <variable key path>`.

Comment: I need to make some modifications in IR according to the value at run time